# C# Unit Test: Retrieve Data from Repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, assert

So I have to create a unit test for my data retrieve, the object i want to get is quite big. 
I have repositories with "GetbyId" (in there we have the retrieve of the dataobject and the mapping). 
I figured out it would be better to create 2 unit tests:

1. Retrieve of the dataobject
2. Mapping to my model

We've already created some test examples and I am checking the entities with saved xmls of the test-entity, so we are quite flexible.
My Problem is with the mapping, since my Model does have some Interfaces I can't serialize it and I don't want to hardcode each example solution (because they are quite a lot too)

Has anyone an idea how I can test the mapper better?

Ps: I know, I am quite the master of explaining things badly, sorry for that.

EDIT:

Here an Example: Since IContact is in Person i can't serialize it so i don't know how to check it easily (this model is an example the real is about  200 rows big without counting the child rows from the interfaces)

```
public Person: IPerson 
{
    public Name {get; set;}
    public IContact {get; set;}
}

public Contact: IContact
{
    public Phone {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some snippet of your model class and the repository class? Will be easier to think about it :)

Comment: I almost always use Json.NET and JSON format instead of XML, it's much more flexible and also easier to read (which is not bad when it comes to testing).

Comment: so the question is how to compare expected object with actual?

Comment: @AlekseyL. well yes that would be it

Comment: Have a look at [fluentassertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison) - you can easily compare object graphs with it

Comment: for mapping object with actual you can use automapper

Comment: @ZoltánTamási i looked into Json.Net and yes it is really easier to read, but i am quite stuck with deserializing the object again. Obviously i can't because of the interfaces, although I can check line per line and look if its equal but I think thats not a good way of testing (btw. have 5500 lines in the jsonObject to check (yeah that big)).

Comment: Maybe your example is simplified compared to the real application, but it's not quite clear why you need such interfaces in a model layer. I've never used interfaces like these, and always felt fine. Usually there is no too much point in introducing interfaces for POCO (or almost POCO) models, but for behavior-oriented classes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use [Compare.net](https://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/) for those cases:

```
//arrange:
var expected = new Person{ Name = "Alice", Contact = new Contact(){Phone = ""}};
CompareLogic compareLogic = new CompareLogic();

//act:
var result = target.GetbyId(1);

//assert:
Assert.IsTrue(compareLogic.Compare(expected, result).AreEqual);
```

Another option is to use [Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison)(for a full disclosure I have no experience with this tool...)

One more option is to create a helper method for asserting, then reuse it in each test.